# Openlayers - 3 wrapper add-on compilation failed in Vaadin

Tags: vaadin7, openlayers-3, geomap

I am getting the following error when compiling the widgetset for openlayers 3 wrapper vaadin addon in eclipse.

```
Starting GWT compiler
Loading inherited module 'com.example.simplescreen.SimplescreenWidgetset'
Loading inherited module 'org.vaadin.addon.vol3.WidgetSet'
  Loading inherited module 'org.vaadin.gwtol3.WidgetSet'
     [ERROR] Unable to find 'org/vaadin/gwtol3/WidgetSet.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
Widgetset compilation failed
```

I added the add-on to the lib folder and also configured the build path. But still the compilation is failed. Anyone help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On the addon page it says: "The wrapper relies on “OpenLayers 3 Wrapper for GWT” add-on to provide the client-side GWT wrappers for the api."
[Open Layers Vaadin Addon page](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/openlayers-3-wrapper-for-vaadin)

So you will need the "Open Layers 3 Wrapper for GWT" addon to make it work. Here's the link to the addon page: [Open Layers Wrapper for GWT](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/openlayers-3-wrapper-for-gwt)

By the way the error message is kind of cryptic so I had a hard time figuring it out myself, but it's basicly that the vaadin version inherits the GWT version's widgetset, but because you don't have the addon installed the xml file is nowhere to be found.

Comment: Thanx @Puppetier . Solved the issue.